# FPGA input into Simulink

Tags: usb, simulink, fpga

I have a DE2i-150 board. I currently have a Simulink model that introduces a sinusoidal input into an external control system. Rather than using the Simulink library for my input how would I use the board instead. I.E. I'd like to output data from the FPGA board which acts as the sinusoidal generator. The board can output data through USB,data, or serial ports. To clarify, the sinusoidal input I'm talking about is merely a Simulink block. Therefore, theoretically I think I should be able to examine the C program that Simulink creates and know which data to output from my board. Would I need to have Quartus running at the same time? Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't quite understand what you want to do exactly, but here are some ideas that you could start looking up:

- writing your own [S-Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/tlc/inlining-s-functions.html) to call an external API that accesses your FPGA and generating C with Simulink Coder or Embedded Coder
- writing [Custom Storage Classes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/custom-storage-classes.html) to call an external API and generating C with Embedded Coder
- converting your model to fixed-point and generating VHDL with [HDL Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/help/hdlcoder/code-generation-1.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into those options. Essentially I'll want to be creating [link](http://www.imc.tue.nl/IMC-main/IMC-main-img300.gif) with the sine wave block being from the FPGA instead.

Comment: Ok. You can ignore the third option, unless you want to generate HDL code for your sine generator too.
Do you already have a way to access your FPGA? Is it memory mapped?

Comment: It is memory mapped and I currently use the Quartus software to access the board.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Quartus software so I can't help you there. If there is any way you can call this software from C code in Simulink then you could use options 1 or 2.

Comment: That's probably the route I'll be taking. Simulink produces C code so I figure I can extract the sinusoidal block from that and try to implement it with my board.